# auth Spring security java configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

when i configured spring by xml, all wokred fine.
Now i trying to make configuration by Java classes.
I have entity User 
And entity Role
In stack of error you can see that security take data from table users instead of user and Roles from table authories instead my table of roles.

This is my configuration security class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Resource(name = "userDetailsServiceImpl")
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource).and()
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                .passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder());

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/control/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/acount/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/reviews/create").authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .failureUrl("/login?err=1")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true);
        }

    }
```

My UserDetailsServiceImpl

```
@Service("userDetailsServiceImpl")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {


        User user = userService.findUserByName(username); //our own User model class
        if(user!=null){
            String password = user.getPassword();


            //Let's populate user roles
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            for(Role role : user.getRoles()){
                authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role.getRoleName()));
            }

            //Now let's create Spring Security User object
            org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User securityUser = null;

            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                    user.getUsername(),
                    user.getPassword(),
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    authorities
            );
        }else{
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found!!!");
        }
    }

}
```

Now, when i try to sign in by form, i see error in console

```
09:29:09,095 ERROR UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:218 - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username,password,enabled from users where username = ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'askme.users' doesn't exist
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username,password,enabled from users where username = ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'askme.users' doesn't exist
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:693)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:725)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:735)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:785)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUsersByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:151)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:102)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'askme.users' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2818)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2157)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2324)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:701)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:642)
    ... 46 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Table 'askme.users' doesn't exist
```

Did you check your database ? How do you populate it ?

Comment: Yes, i check. In my entities annonation i did not change nothing.  When i set  auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("test").password("testtest").roles("Admin");  and try login, all good and all entities loading with all mapping data

Comment: So you're telling us that the _InMemoryAuthentication_ is working but it's not working when you try to use your database to authenticate ? Can you share your entities ?

Comment: https://github.com/odahovskiy/askme/tree/configureAppByAnnotation/src/main/java/com/askme/entity

Comment: Now i instead of this approach, try write custom auth provider,  and now i can sign in, but SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); return empty principial when i signed in or anonymous.

Comment: Did you try to add _@Table_ on your _User_ entity ? Something like : 
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable{}

Comment: No, i didn`t, But if i does not add annonation, hibernate get simple class name or no?

Now i write provider and this provider are getting data from db, but context  does not contains principial name

https://github.com/odahovskiy/askme/blob/configureAppByAnnotation/src/main/java/com/askme/config/CustomAuthProvider.java

Comment: According to the stacktrace, it's using the name of your class and package : _askme.User_ but it can't find it.

Comment: try to add this annotation, but nothing change. Secuity return bad credentials exception.

Comment: I am not sure it is related to this, but i did get the same exception when i tried to setup custom authentication using mysql. I think some operating systems, the database table names are case sensitive and some other operating systems they are not, for instance when i ran this config in Mac Osx it worked .. But when i ran it in windows or linux i got the same exception as you got.. In my case i set the table name case to lower in mysql.conf